# Displaying sub-categories next to the main categories using CSS after PHP generation

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

1: I have a hierichal table of categories in my database: 
[image]
2: I made this PHP script which turns this table into HTML: http://pastie.org/4591869

3: The HTML looks like this:

```
<script>
                    function toggleSubCategories(button) {
                        button = $(button);
                        button.parent().next().each(function() {
                            $(this).css('display') == 'none' ? $(this).css('display', 'inline') : $(this).css('display', 'none');
                        });
                    }
                </script>
                <div id="catlist">
                    <li>
                        <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Lots</button>
                    </li>
                    <ul style="display: inline; ">
                        <li>
                            <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-info">Town Lots</button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-info">Bux Lots</button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-info">Wild Lots</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <li>
                        <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Items</button>
                    </li>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-info">Blocks</button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-info">Tools</button>
                        </li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-success">Enchanted</button>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-success">Normal</button>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>
                    <li>
                        <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Services</button>
                    </li>
                    <ul style="display: none; ">
                        <li>
                            <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-info">Trader Services</button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-info">Constructor Services</button>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-info">Politician Services</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <li>
                        <button onclick="toggleSubCategories(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Labour</button>
                    </li>
                </div>
```

4: I also have this CSS file:

```
#catlist {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
}

#catlist ul {
    list-style: inherit;
    display: none;
}

#catlist ul li {
    display: block;
    list-style: inherit;
}

#catlist button {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    display: inline;
}
```

5: This currently looks like this (after I click on the first main category): 
[image]
6: But I want it to like this: 
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I'm literally pulling my hair out here.
I'm using CSS3, HTML5, JQuery, PHP and Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change positioning of `#catlist ul`. Do:

```
#catlist { position: relative; }
#catlist ul { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 220px; }
```

Haven't tested, but should work. Next time add jsfiddle with code instead of pictures, this will let us play with your exact code and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for vertical css menu, have a look at [this page](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples)